# Integration with our Inventory System

Tags: product, products-management, sales, inventory, cataloginventory

I want to integrate our Magento website with Inventory management system. for this task we are development 2 ways syncing service which will update Magento db & Inventory system also;

How to update products (Need table structure and db flow)
How to update inventory on purchase and sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you check out the Magento API!. Specifically

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/Inventory.html

Regards

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have started to read APIs , can you provide link for sample source code  (if any) of .net or PHP